# How to extract text from pdf in java ignoring images?

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I'm trying to use PDFBox to get text out of a pdf document that I then need to split into paragraphs and process further. I can't find a solution using the updated versions, I need to set it up as to avoid that the OCR picks up text within images or footnotes/pagenumbers that get in between the parahraphs' text. Im trying this but it doesn't seem to remove anything

```
        String parsedText;
        File f = new File(pdffilename);
        PDFParser parser = new PDFParser(new RandomAccessFile(f, "r"));
        parser.parse();

        COSDocument cosDoc = parser.getDocument();
        PDDocument pdDoc = new PDDocument(cosDoc);

        PDDocumentCatalog catalog = pdDoc.getDocumentCatalog();

        for (Object pageObj : catalog.getPages()) {
            PDPage page = (PDPage) pageObj;
            PDResources resources = page.getResources();

            for (COSName xObjectName : resources.getXObjectNames()) {
                resources.getCOSObject().removeItem(xObjectName);
                PDXObject xObject = resources.getXObject(xObjectName);

                if (xObject instanceof PDFormXObject || xObject instanceof PDImageXObject) {
                    resources.getCOSObject().removeItem(xObjectName);
                } 
            }
        }

        PDFTextStripper pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();

        pdfStripper.setSortByPosition(true);
        parsedText = pdfStripper.getText(pdDoc);
        cosDoc.close();

        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("src/main/resources/pdf.txt");
        pw.print(parsedText);
        pw.close();
```